# Trying to extract/count the unique characters in a string (of class character)

Tags: r, character, unique, distinct

Hi what I am trying to do is count the number of unique characters in a string. Here is what my dataframe looks like

```
Text            unique char count
banana              3
banana12            5
Ace@343             6
```

**Upper/lower cases doesn't matter, what I am trying to get is unique chars(numbers, letters) in the output**

I have tried unique, distinct functions etc however they provide the out for entire column within the column  but I need it for each corresponding cell as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can do:

```r
df$char_count <- sapply(strsplit(df$Text, ""), function(x) length(unique(x)))

df
#>       Text char_count
#> 1   banana          3
#> 2 banana12          5
#> 3  Ace@343          6
```

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(Text = c("banana", "banana12", "Ace@343"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: And if I had to count only the number of special characters as "@" in above example which is one,  I tried - df$char_count <- str_count(df$Text,"[[:punct:]]"), works howevere gives 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use `regex` to do the count

```
df %>%
   mutate(char_count = str_count(Text, "(.)(?!.*\\1)"))

      Text char_count
1   banana          3
2 banana12          5
3  Ace@343          6
```

Comment: Ty Onyambu however I am now trying to extract only the spl chars, so in my question I just need "@" to be the out in the next column as 1 , for rest it should be 0 as there is no spl char. I tried df$char_count <- str_count(df$Text,"[[:punct:]]") , didnt work

Comment: @vicky the above gives the expected results as posted in the question. There was No mention of special characters.

Comment: @vicky in the case of special characters, it depends what exactly you define as special characters, eg `df %>%mutate(Text = str_count(Text, '\\W'))` works for me. Also `df %>%mutate(Text = str_count(Text, '[[:punct:]]'))` works

Comment: Hi, I have already used [[:punct:]] because it is short for  # $ % & .... @

Comment: @vicky yes, and that works on my end ie gives 0,0,1

Comment: not sure, what am i doing wrong, trying it again

Comment: checking punctuation because I am getting error Error: unexpected '=' in "df %>%mutate(Text="

Comment: @vicky I don't realy know what you mean by that. just copy the code the way I wrote it. Also, please consider closing the question by selection one of the provided answers. Note that whatver you are asking right now is totally a new question which can be asked and answered. It is not *counting unique characters in a string* but rathe *counting punctuations in a string*

Comment: sure, I will close the question,